# How to reference a folder in visual studio 2012

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I'm working in a multiplatform C++ game for iOS, Android and Windows 8. Trying to avoid to have 3 copies of my sources ( Updates are available for all platforms at once ), I'm using a folder structure like this:

```
+-+-[Game project folder]
  |
  +-[Android] (contains Eclipse project files)
  |
  +-[iOS] (contains Xcode project files)
  |
  +-[Win] (contains VS 2012 project files)
  |
  +-+-[Sources] (contains the engine, app and assets)
    |
    +-[engine]
    |
    +-[app]
    |
    +-[resources]
```

This structure works awesome in iOS and Android because it's easy to reference the folders in Xcode and Eclipse.

**How can I reference the sources folder in Visual Studio 2012 project without copy the sources inside the win folder?**.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: What do you mean by "reference a folder"?

Comment: My fault, thanks for editing.

Comment: I'm trying to say that can I link this folder in my project without copy it inside. In xcode you only need to drag the folder in the project and select folder reference.

Answer (score 0):

When you choose "Add Existing Item" in Visual Studio, you can choose to **add it as a link** from the "Add" button (just click the arrow to its right).

[image]

Comment: I tried but the option seems to be removed in visual studio 2012 :_(